# MySQL Adding COMMENT to a Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I'm translating an old database SyBase to MySQL and I have this DDL Query:

```
ALTER TABLE "DBA"."tab_prodotto"
  ADD FOREIGN KEY "fkey_idlinea" ("tpr_idlin") 
  REFERENCES "DBA"."linea" ("lin_id")
go
COMMENT ON FOREIGN KEY "DBA"."tab_prodotto"."fkey_idlinea" IS
'Riferimento linea'
go
```

The Alter part of query works well, but I have troubles on COMMENT. I already know that I can alter a column for adding a COMMENT, but is that possible for foreign keys too? If yes, how? I haven't find nothing special on documentation.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [MySQL reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) shows the allowed syntax for the `FOREIGN KEY` command to be:

```
  [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
  [index_name] (index_col_name, ...)
  REFERENCES tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
  [ON DELETE reference_option]
  [ON UPDATE reference_option]

reference_option:
   RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
```

There is no allowable `COMMENT` section. It looks like this is not allowed.

The manual I referenced above is from version 5.6. I checked versions 5.1 and 5.5 and the syntax is the same.

Comment: You are right. MySQL is very limited when it comes to comments on "objects" in the database.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry to say! If you believe the answer was correct I'd appreciate an upvote/acceptance-- Thanks and good luck!

Comment: I was waiting for someone else to vonfirm. Upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

[Image showing Workbench allowing entry of a Foreign Key Comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAVaH.png)Curiously, MySQL Workbench allows a Foreign Key Comment to be entered on the foreign key, but it does not generate it when synching to a database.

Entering a Foreign Key Comment in MySQL Workbench causes that table to keep showing as needing changes to be applied to the DB when synching the model... very annoying!

This is a bug -- Workbench should not allow entry of foreign key comments if MySQL doesn't actually support them.

Related -- column and table comments which exceed permitted lengths cause repeated syncs to show up too -- MySQL should limit the # of chars that can be typed in the comment boxes to prevent these problems.