# How to set the foreign key name in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

How can I set the name of a foreign key in php `laravel`?

```
Schema::table('TABLE_NAME', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreign(XXX)
            ->references(XXX)
            ->on('REF_TABLE')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

            // HOW TO ACHIEVE SOMETHING LIKE THIS?
            //->name('Custom name of foreign key.')
            //->comment('Custom comment for foreign key.')        
    });
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can specify a custom name by filling the second foreign param :

```
->foreign('XXX', 'my_custom_name')
```

Answer (score 2):

when you build your foreign key column, you can build it like:

```
 $table->UnsignedBigInteger('xxx')->comment("comment for this column");
```

see this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-comment-on-table-column-using-schema-builder).

you can also find the details in Laravel [column-modifiers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#column-modifiers).

Comment: Okay, but that is for each column (great tip anyways!). How can I add a comment to my foreign key constraint?

Comment: there is no allowable comment on constraint it self, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11016132/10573560

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you!

Comment: and alsow you can specify a name for the forein key it self, see:https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Schema/ForeignKeyDefinition.html

Answer (score 1):

You can make the foreign key in the following way:-

```
        $table->unsignedInteger('XXXX')
            ->nullable();
        $table->foreign('XXXX')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('REF_TABLE')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Answer (score 0):

What @Shwetank mentioned worked. However, `$table->unsignedInteger('XXXX')` needed to be changed to `$table->UnsignedBigInteger('XXXX')`. Example:

```php
$table->UnsignedBigInteger('XXXX')
            ->nullable();
        $table->foreign('XXXX')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('REF_TABLE')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
```

Note: Laravel 9.x